# How to configure client authentication with apache.commons.net.ftps?

Tags: java, ssl, apache-commons-net, ftps, authentication

I implemented a FTPS client (FTP over SSL/TLS) in java using the *apache.commons.net*-framework. 
It is configured to do explicit security on the default port 21.

```
ftpsClient = new FTPSClient(false);
ftpsClient.setTrustManager(getConfiguration().getCertificatesManager());
ftpsClient.connect(getConfiguration().getHostName(), getConfiguration().getPort());
```

As long as I don't enforce client-authentication on the server, everything works fine. 
But I need to enable client-authentication, so I enforce it on the server and configured the client-system properties:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="D:/.../ftps-client-auth.keystore"
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword="*****"
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=JKS
```

What I got was the same as if I did not set the system properties:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:136)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1806)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:986)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1170)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1197)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1181)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient.sslNegotiation(FTPSClient.java:265)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient._connectAction_(FTPSClient.java:207)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:172)
    at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:192)
```

The server-log says:

```
DEBUG: Client "<my ip address>", "SSL_accept failed: error:140890C7:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE:peer did not return a certificate"
```

Seems right - I enabled *-Djavax.net.debug=all*, what shows that the server sends a list of CNs it accepts, but the client sends an empty certificate chain.

- **What have I done wrong?**
- **Do I need to do some configuration programatically?**
- **Do the certificates or the private key need to support anything special for SSL/TLS?**

Comment: How did you set up your server? Having troubles setting up a server that enforces SSL and client authentication. Any help as to what you used to set it up?

Comment: @trynacode a colleague set up a vsftp server with client authentication. Unfortunately, I don't know the settings he used.

Comment: I'lll look into that then Andy. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out: you need to programmatically set a `KeyManager`. 
Setting the system properties (`-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore`, ...) is not sufficient, because the the framework does not use Suns `SSLSocketFactory`.

Example:

```
ftpsClient = new FTPSClient(false);
ftpsClient.setTrustManager(TrustManagerUtils.getAcceptAllTrustManager());
KeyManager keyManager = org.apache.commons.net.util.KeyManagerUtils.createClientKeyManager(new File(keystorePath), keystorePass);
ftpsClient.setKeyManager(keyManager);
ftpsClient.connect(getConfiguration().getHostName(), getConfiguration().getPort());
```

You may want to choose a different Trust-Manager, e.g. one that is based on a Java-keystore. The utils provide a method for that, too: [`TrustManagerUtils.getDefaultTrustManager(keystore)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/util/TrustManagerUtils.html#getDefaultTrustManager(java.security.KeyStore))

Comment: What this getConfiguration(). ??

Comment: getConfiguration ?? where do you find it?

Comment: I updated the example. Take a look at TrustManagerUtils to create an instance.