# How to create DefaultFtpsSessionFactory instance with the help of certificate

Tags: java, spring-integration

I am trying to use `org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpsSessionFactory` for my FTPS client, but I do not have userId or Password. I have *.cer file. How do I create instance of session factory using certificate. So far I have looked at

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-cryptography/certificatefactory.html

[How do I configure client authentication with generated certificate in apache-commons net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19173394/how-do-i-configure-client-authentication-with-generated-certificate-in-apache-co)

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html

I just couldn't find any straight forward usage to using certificate while creating ftpsclient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not done it, but I think you will have to create a subclass of `DefaultFtpsSessionFactory`, override `createClientInstance()` to use one of the `FTPSClient` constructors that takes an `SSLContext`.

You would have to initialize the SSL context with a `KeyManager` that has been initialized from a keystore that contains the certificate.

`spring-integration-ip` has [some code that does this for TCP connections](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-ip/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/ip/tcp/connection/DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport.java#L72).

Comment: Looks like he also has a concern about `username`, which is used in the `AbstractFtpSessionFactory.createClient()` anyway for the `client.login()` and cannot be empty...

Comment: Well, I believe the certificate is just to authenticate (trust) the SSL connection; I don't believe it's used to identify the user (even with an sftp public/private key pair you need a user name; the private key is used instead of a password).

Comment: @GaryRussell thank you so much. I just needed a hint. I will try that.

Comment: @GaryRussell - I tried that but it did not work. Most of the implementation needs password.